# Constructor without argument is not called in this program

Tags: c++, class

I wrote this simple program in cpp.But constructor without argument is not called.Please help me by saying why is it not getting called..

Out put for the program is

```
623423
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.07689 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
class Date{
int day,month,year;
public:
Date();
Date(int,int);
Date(int);
Date(int,int,int);  

};
Date :: Date(){
    day=10;
    month=5;
    year=19;
    std::cout<<"********************************************";
    std::cout<<day<<month<<year;
}
Date :: Date(int a){
    day=a;
    std::cout<<day;
}
Date ::Date (int a,int b){
    day=a;
    month=b;
    std::cout<<day<<month;
}
Date ::Date(int a,int b,int c){
    day=a;
    month=b;
    year=c;
    std::cout<<day<<month<<year;
}
int main(){
    Date one();
    Date two(6);
    Date three(2,3,4);
    Date four(2,3);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of C++, where `Date one();` declares a *function* that takes no arguments and returns a `Date` by value. Either use `Date one;` or curly braces `Date one{};`. Note that using curly braces could mean different things depending on your constructors.

Comment: Thank you programmer dude...Awesome explanation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _Welcome to the wonderful world of C++, where `Date one();` declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Date` by value._ Did I (correctly) read some kind of frustration between the lines? ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Perhaps a little bit... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date one();
```

It is not doing what you expect. It is declaring a function called one which returns a `Date` by value as correctly said by @[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) in the comment section. You can write either `Date one;` or you can use C++11 uniform initialization `Date one{};`